# How to send GET request with headers by Spring

Tags: spring, rest, jakarta-ee

It will call another REST API with a GET request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxxx/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody GetObjet GET( @PathVariable("id") String id,
                @RequestHeader(value="X-Auth-Token") String Token) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();        
    headers.add("X-Auth-Token", Token);

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    ResponseEntity<GetObjet> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, GetObjet.class);

    return response.getBody();
}
```

Always 400 Error. It means that bad request or some errors in the request body. But this is GET so the resquest bodys is always empty. So this way to add header may be not right. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `url`? Why do you put this code inside a method that listens for `GET` requests? Did you try to use the client part of your code as a standalone client and not as part of a server?

Comment: @LutzHorn url is the adresse of another rest api. It's a little complex to answer your question. I need my api to call another api. I know it's not good but no choice because of my private problem TOT

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the headers including the notation `@RequestHeader`  in your method

```
public void displayHeaderInfo(@RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding") String encoding,
                              @RequestHeader("Keep-Alive") long keepAlive)  {

}
```

o

[You can read more about the request here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

And the other way to abtain the URL is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/restURL")
     public String serveRest(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){
     //Use headers to get the information about all the request headers
     long contentLength = headers.getContentLength();
    ...
     StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(body));
     YourObject obj = (YourObject) jaxb2Mashaller.unmarshal(source);
     ...
     }
```

Comment: But now the problem is that resttemplate.exchange doesnt work when we send a GET Request with headers

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
RestTemplate.getForEntity(url, GetObject.class);
```

You have some methods to request data from a rest API, such as `getForEntity` and `getForObject`, use the one you needed.

Comment: Thy, but by this way, how could we add headers?